# Free solutions for exporting a single window from one system to another in windows - the equivalent of x11 forwarding between windows systems

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, remote-desktop, remote-access

For various reasons, i need to forward a single window, as transparently as possible from one windows system to another.

Raw performance is not an issue, there should be a dedicated gig-e connection between the systems in question and i will not be running software where input latency will be a huge issue. I will also need sounds to be handled by the system in which the software is running

The system running the software can run either windows XP professional, or windows 7 professional, and the system i want to forward the window to will be windows 7 professional.

[seamlessrdp](http://www.cendio.com/seamlessrdp/) comes close, but it requires a linux client

Comment: I'm a little confused by the downvote - if there's something actually *wrong* with the question, let me know in comments so i can make it better

Answer (score 0):

You can do the equivilent of seamless RDP with windows via Remote Apps over RDP.  This is a feature of Windows Server 2008, but has been made to work with registry hacks and RDP file tweaks on W7, Vista and XP SP3.

It is a bit long to reproduce here, but here is the how to [link.](https://web.archive.org/web/20210117115603/http://geekswithblogs.net/twickers/archive/2009/12/18/137048.aspx)

Comment: there's no 'TsAppAllowList' entry in my registry by default. The gui configurator seems to have set it up but the rdp file it generates asks for a password, then just closes

Comment: Yeah it looks like it needs Ultimate or Enterprise on the host in order to enable TS - what are you running?

Comment: as per the question, windows 7 professional on both ends at the moment - i can swap the server end to xp pro tho